# Sorted trie implementation in C

Tags: c, linked-list, hash-map, trie

I wanted to store some dictionary data (key/value pairs of strings) in C, and decided to use a trie.

I found what looks like a good implementation [here](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2012/11/trie-implementation-in-c.html), along with some nice notes.

In this implementation, each node in the trie is a trie itself. Each node has `next`, `prev`, `child`, and `parent` properties, pointing to other nodes or `NULL`.

I've modified the code as follows:

- Node values are of type `void *` instead of type `int`.
- Keys are kept in alphabetical order as new nodes are added. This isn't much trouble, since tries to a lot of the work naturally. This should improve search time, since you can stop looking for a character once you find a character in the same position with a greater value.

  This might slow down adding new keys, except that adding new keys involves searching for existing keys, so adding sorted keys could possibly be faster in some cases.
- Added a "dump" function.
- Formatted and refactored.

---

### Public functions for manipulating tries

- `Trie_create()` creates a new trie and returns a pointer to it.
- `Trie_dump()` dumps all keys and values in the trie to `stdout`.
- `Trie_get()` gets the value at a given key.
- `Trie_put()` puts a value in the given key.
- `Trie_remove()` removes the given key from the trie.

---

### `trie.h`

```
typedef struct Trie_t Trie;

Trie *Trie_create();

const char *Trie_get(Trie *root, const char *key);

void Trie_put(Trie *root, const char *key, void *data);

void Trie_remove(Trie *root, const char *key);

void Trie_dump(Trie *t);
```

---

### `trie.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "trie.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Trie_t {
  char key;
  void *value;
  Trie *next;
  Trie *prev;
  Trie *child;
  Trie *parent;
  Trie *marker;
};

Trie *Trie_createNode(const char key, void *data) {
  Trie *t = NULL;
  t = (Trie *)malloc(sizeof(Trie));

  if (!t) {
    printf("Malloc failed\n");
    return t;
  }

  t->key = key;
  t->value = data;
  t->next = NULL;
  t->child = NULL;
  t->parent = NULL;
  t->prev = NULL;
  t->marker = NULL;

  return t;
}

void Trie_unlink(Trie *t) {
  if (t->next)
    t->next->prev = t->prev;
  if (t->prev)
    t->prev->next = t->next;
  else if (t->parent)
    t->parent->child = t->next;

  t->prev = 0;
  t->next = 0;
  t->parent = 0;
}

void Trie_insertAfter(Trie *oldTrie, Trie *newTrie) {
  Trie_unlink(newTrie);
  newTrie->parent = oldTrie->parent;
  newTrie->next = oldTrie->next;
  newTrie->prev = oldTrie;
  if (newTrie->next)
    newTrie->next->prev = newTrie;
  oldTrie->next = newTrie;
}

void Trie_insertBefore(Trie *oldTrie, Trie *newTrie) {
  Trie_insertAfter(oldTrie, newTrie);
  Trie_insertAfter(newTrie, oldTrie);
}

Trie *Trie_search(Trie *root, const char *key) {
  while (1) {
    Trie *t;
    int match = 0;
    for (t = root; t && t->key <= *key; t = t->next) {
      if (t->key == *key) {
        match = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!match)
      return NULL;
    if (*key == '\0')
      return t;
    root = t->child;
    key++;
  }
}

void Trie_putPart(Trie *root, const char *key, void *data){
  Trie *t;
  for (t = root; *key; t = t->child) {
    t->child = Trie_createNode(*key, NULL);
    t->child->parent = t;
    key++;
  }

  t->child = Trie_createNode('\0', data);
  t->child->parent = t;

}

void Trie_put(Trie *root, const char *key, void *data) {
  Trie *t = NULL;
  Trie *current = NULL;
  Trie *tmp = NULL;

  if (!root)
    return;

  t = root->child;
  current = Trie_search(t, key);

  if (current) {
    current->value = data;
    return;
  }

  if (!t) {
    Trie_putPart(root, key, data);
    return;
  }

  while (*key != '\0') {
    if (*key != t->key)
      break;
    key++;
    t = t->child;
  }

  while (t->next && (t->key < *key)) {
    if (*key == t->next->key) {
      key++;
      Trie_put(t->next, key, data);
      return;
    }
    t = t->next;
  }

  tmp = Trie_createNode(*key, NULL);

  if (t->key > tmp->key) {
    Trie_insertBefore(t, tmp);
  } else {
    Trie_insertAfter(t, tmp);
  }

  key++;

  Trie_putPart(tmp, key, data);
  return;
}

void Trie_remove(Trie *root, const char *key) {
  Trie *t = NULL;

  if (!root || !key)
    return;

  for (t = Trie_search(root->child, key); t; t = t->parent) {
    if (t->prev || t->next) {
      Trie_unlink(t);
      free(t);
      return;
    }
  }

}

Trie *Trie_create() {
  return Trie_createNode('\0', 0);
}

void *Trie_getRaw(Trie *root, const char *key) {
  Trie *t = Trie_search(root->child, key);
  return t ? t->value : 0;
}

const char *Trie_get(Trie *root, const char *key) {
  return Trie_getRaw(root, key);
}

void Trie_dumpf(Trie *root, const char * keysep, const char * valsep) {
  Trie *t = root;
  Trie *tmp;

  while (t) {
    if (t->value) {
      tmp = root;
      while (tmp) {
        printf("%c", tmp->key);
        tmp = tmp->marker;
      }
      printf("%s%s%s", keysep, (char *)t->value, valsep);
      while (t && !t->next)
        t = t->parent;
      if (t)
        t = t->next;
      if (t && t->parent)
        t->parent->marker = t;
    } else {
      t = t->child;
      t->parent->marker = t;
    }
  }
}

void Trie_dump(Trie *t) {
  Trie_dumpf(t, ": ", "\n");
}
```

---

### `example.c`

```
int main() {
  Trie *t = Trie_create();
  Trie_put(t, "name", "Testman");
  Trie_put(t, "address", "123 main st");
  Trie_put(t, "max-y", "200");
  Trie_put(t, "max-z", "300");
  Trie_put(t, "country", "USA");
  Trie_put(t, "city", "Nowhere");
  Trie_put(t, "max-x", "100");

  Trie_remove(t, "max-y");
  Trie_remove(t, "badkey");

  Trie_dump(t);

  printf("max xyz = %s,%s,%s\n",  
      Trie_get(t, "max-x"),  Trie_get(t, "max-y"), Trie_get(t, "max-z"));

  return 0;
}
```

> **output**
>
> address: 123 main st
>   city: Nowhere
>   country: USA
>   max-x: 100
>   max-z: 300
>   name: Testman
>   max xyz = 100,(null),300

---

### Questions

Some things I'm wondering about:

- In the original code, `TrieAdd` and `TrieRemove` take a pointer to a pointer to a trie, instead of a pointer to a trie. I couldn't see any reason for doing this, so I changed it. Is this alright? What reason could the author have had for doing this?
- I hacked up `Trie_remove` pretty badly. I was confused about this code at first, but I think I understand it now. Stilll, if anyone wants to comment on this, I'm interested. Eventually I want to write `Trie_destroy()` to complement `Trie_create()`.
- Any thoughts on the sorting approach and any potential cost/benefit in terms of performance? Should I consider doing a binary search to improve search time even further?
- Tries want void pointers as data, but in practice I'm giving them strings. I did this to keep things flexible in case I want to store complex data later. Is this too weird?
- Is there any redundancy to eliminate or obvious enhancements that should be made?
- Any new bugs I created that weren't in the original code?
- Any old bugs I overlooked that are still in my code?
- Any comments on `Trie_dump`?

---

### Original code

Varun Gupta's [trie implementation in c](http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2012/11/trie-implementation-in-c.html), included here for reference.

```
/*trie.h*/
typedef int trieVal_t;

typedef struct trieNode {
    char key;
    trieVal_t value;
    struct trieNode *next;
    struct trieNode *prev;
    struct trieNode *children;
    struct trieNode *parent;
} trieNode_t;

trieNode_t* TrieSearch(trieNode_t *root, const char *key);
/*trie.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "trie.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEBUG

trieNode_t *TrieCreateNode(char key, int data)
{
    trieNode_t *node = NULL;
    node = (trieNode_t *)malloc(sizeof(trieNode_t));

    if(NULL == node)
    {
        printf("Malloc failed\n");
        return node;
    }

    node->key = key;
    node->next = NULL;
    node->children = NULL;
    node->value = data;
    node->parent= NULL;
    node->prev= NULL;
    return node;
}

void TrieAdd(trieNode_t **root, char *key, int data)
{
    trieNode_t *pTrav = NULL;

    if(NULL == *root)
    {
        printf("NULL tree\n");
        return;
    }
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\nInserting key %s: \n",key);
#endif
    pTrav = (*root)->children;

    if(TrieSearch(pTrav, key))
    {
        printf("Duplicate!\n");
        return;
    }

    if(pTrav == NULL)
    {
        /*First Node*/
        for(pTrav = *root; *key; pTrav = pTrav->children)
        {
            pTrav->children = TrieCreateNode(*key, 0xffffffff);
            pTrav->children->parent = pTrav;
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Inserting: %c\n",pTrav->children->key);
#endif
            key++;
        }

        pTrav->children = TrieCreateNode('\0', data);
        pTrav->children->parent = pTrav;
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Inserting: %c\n",pTrav->children->key);
#endif
        return;
    }

    while(*key != '\0')
    {
        if(*key == pTrav->key)
        {
            key++;
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf("Traversing child: %c\n",pTrav->children->key);
#endif
            pTrav = pTrav->children;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    while(pTrav->next)
    {
        if(*key == pTrav->next->key)
        {
            key++;
            TrieAdd(&(pTrav->next), key, data);
            return;
        }
        pTrav = pTrav->next;
    }

    pTrav->next = TrieCreateNode(*key, 0xffffffff);
    pTrav->next->parent = pTrav->parent;
    pTrav->next->prev = pTrav;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Inserting %c as neighbour of %c \n",pTrav->next->key, pTrav->key);
#endif

    key++;

    for(pTrav = pTrav->next; *key; pTrav = pTrav->children)
    {
        pTrav->children = TrieCreateNode(*key, 0xffffffff);
        pTrav->children->parent = pTrav;
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Inserting: %c\n",pTrav->children->key);
#endif
        key++;
    }

    pTrav->children = TrieCreateNode('\0', data);
    pTrav->children->parent = pTrav;
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Inserting: %c\n",pTrav->children->key);
#endif
    return;
}

trieNode_t* TrieSearch(trieNode_t *root, const char *key)
{
    trieNode_t *level = root;
    trieNode_t *pPtr = NULL;

    int lvl=0;
    while(1)
    {
        trieNode_t *found = NULL;
        trieNode_t *curr;

        for (curr = level; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
        {
            if (curr->key == *key)
            {
                found = curr;
                lvl++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if (*key == '\0')
        {
            pPtr = curr;
            return pPtr;
        }

        level = found->children;
        key++;
    }
}

void TrieRemove(trieNode_t **root, char *key)
{
    trieNode_t *tPtr = NULL;
    trieNode_t *tmp = NULL;

    if(NULL == *root || NULL == key)
        return;

    tPtr = TrieSearch((*root)->children, key);

    if(NULL == tPtr)
    {
        printf("Key not found in trie\n");
        return;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if( tPtr->prev && tPtr->next)
        {
            tmp = tPtr;
            tPtr->next->prev = tPtr->prev;
            tPtr->prev->next = tPtr->next;
            free(tmp);
            break;
        }
        else if(tPtr->prev && !(tPtr->next))
        {
            tmp = tPtr;
            tPtr->prev->next = NULL;
            free(tmp);
            break;
        }
        else if(!(tPtr->prev) && tPtr->next)
        {
            tmp = tPtr;
            tPtr->parent->children = tPtr->next;
            free(tmp);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = tPtr;
            tPtr = tPtr->parent;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the Wikipedia page on Trie, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie I see that each node has one parent and an arbitrary number of children; if the key is a char the limit would be 255 children (or maybe less if you restrict yourself to printable chars).  Yet your `Trie` structure has a very different arrangement. As your structure doesn't match my naive expectation, and you have no comments indicating how the tree is actually arranged I didn't review the functionality of the code, but instead just picked as few nits:

- put standard headers before your own
- start functions with the `{` in the first column (some tools rely on this - or used to anyway)
- make local functions static. And static functions don't need the `Trie_` prefix.
- use const in function parameters and variables wherever possible
- the `key` parameter to `Trie_createNode` need not be `const` (although it does no harm)
- use of braces on single-line conditions etc is generally preferred (although noisy)
- use `perror` to print error messages (eg `perror("malloc");`)
- don't cast malloc.  eg. this

  ```
  Trie *t = NULL;
  t = (Trie *)malloc(sizeof(Trie));
  ```

  should be:

  ```
  Trie *t = malloc(sizeof(Trie)); /* or malloc(sizeof *t) */
  ```
- nested loops are best avoided. For example in `Trie_search`, the for-loop could be extracted to a function (eg `find_key`).
- the `while(1)` in `Trie_search` would be better as a for-loop

  ```
  Trie *Trie_search(const Trie *root, const char *key)
  {
      for (const Trie *t = root;
           (t = find_key(t, *key)) != NULL; ++key, t = t->child) {

          if (*key == '\0') {
              return t;
          }
      }
      return NULL;
  }
  ```

  Note that this loop (and your original) allow the search to start even if `key` is an empty string.  I also get the impression that the '\0' is entered as a node in the tree, which seems very odd, but maybe I misunderstood the code.
- the two while loops in `Trie_put` could probably be extracted into functions

Comment: Thanks, your comments are very helpful, I'll update my answer in a bit with changes and an explanation of the children thing (but yes, the `\0` is entered... only the `\0` entries have values. Each node's key is a single character).

Comment: Sorry for the late followup on this. I created another trie question [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25359/simple-trie-implementation-in-javascript), partly to try to explain the children thing. I'll probably end up rewriting this to be more like that code eventually.