# Simple trie implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linked-list, hash-map, trie

After experimenting with a [sorted trie implementation in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25248/sorted-trie-implementation-in-c), I felt that I understood tries pretty well, but was having trouble explaining how they work. Since the C code was based on existing code, I wanted to try it again in another language, from scratch.

Here's what I came up with. I tried to make it as minimal as possible. These tries aren't sorted, and nodes only reference a `child` and `next` node; `parent` and `prev` aren't used. I did give the "leaves" of the trie a `name` property, which is the full key. This isn't currently used, but it's useful for debugging, and it would be useful if a trie iterator were added (like `Trie_dump` from the question linked above).

I'm interested in feedback on the code itself this time, but not so much on things like white space, braces, semicolons, etc. I'm comfortable with the formatting the way it is. I'd be interested in an alternative to that labeled loop, though, and all other feedback is welcome.

---

### Trie structure

Each node in the trie can have a `key`, a `value`, a `next` node, and a `child` node. In this diagram, each node is represented by a circle. The "root" node is at the left, the green "leaf" nodes are at the right, and the "branch" nodes are in the middle.

Each `key` is a single character (circled letters below). The "branches" have keys, while each "leaf" holds a value.

[image: Trie diagram]

In the diagram, nodes appear to have multiple children. For example, the first "r" node has "u" and "o" children. Internally, nodes just have a `child` property; the first child. The next child is available in the first child's `next` property, and so on. It may help to think of `child` as "first child" and `next` as "next sibling."

---

### `trie.js`

```
function Trie(parent, prev, key, value) {
    if (key !== void 0)
        this.key = key;      // single-character key
    if (value !== void 0)
        this.value = value;  // user-defined value
    if (prev)
        prev.next = this;    // next sibling node
    else if (parent)
        parent.child = this; // first child node
}

// put a key/value pair in the trie
Trie.prototype.put = function(name, value) {
    var i = 0, t = this, len = name.length, prev, parent;
    down: while (t.child) {
        parent = t;
        t = t.child;
        // if first child didn't match, get next sibling
        while (t.key != name[i]) {
            if (!t.next) {
                prev = t;
                t = parent;
                break down;
            }
            t = t.next;
        }
        // key already exists, update the value
        if (++i > len) {
            t.value = value;
            return;
        }
    }
    // found any existing parts of the key, add the rest
    t = new this.constructor(t, prev, name[i]);
    while (++i <= len)
        t = new this.constructor(t, null, name[i]);
    t.name = name;
    t.value = value;
};

// get a value from the trie at the given key
Trie.prototype.get = function(name) {
    var i = 0, t = this.child, len = name.length;
    while (t) {
        if (t.key == name[i]) {
            if (i == len)
                return t.value;
            t = t.child;
            ++i;
        } else {
            t = t.next;
        }
    }
};
```

---

### Demos

Here are links to a few demos. The simple demo puts some test data in a trie, gets it back out, and dumps it to the console. The fancy demo puts the same test data in a trie and draws a diagram like the one above.

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Yttq

Fancy demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Yttq/1/

Comment: Just personal preference, but I think you're using a weird coding style. `while (++i <= len)` isn't something comprehensible. Not using braces for `if`, etc. The code is pretty, but it feels like magic on first sight.

Comment: `break down;` :)

Comment: @mellamokb I couldn't resist...

Comment: @Dagg Well, other than my solution and Florian's "no magic" suggestion, it looks like all I can suggest is to use verbose variable names. If you plan to do sorted tries, binary tree? I think it would increase access times due to depth, but let's have jsPerf be the judge of that.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, my optimization is an overhaul of your method. The concept is still tries. But I went for the JS route for several reasons:

- We're in JavaScript. Linked lists in C would be like Arrays/Objects in JS. Since we have them available, why not use them instead?
- In tries, you use a key for each entry. You'd have to loop over and find it when using linked lists or arrays. In JS, we have objects that are key-value pairs, which make it a bit easier to implement.
- [Performance is a bit better](http://jsperf.com/tries#run), except on Opera browsers. Performance may be due to the lesser loops and property access.
- The code is shorter

The structure:

```
{
  "t": {
    "key": "t",
    "r": {
      "key": "r",
      "u": {
        "key": "u",
        "e": {
          "key": "e",
          "value": "yes",
          "name": "true"
        },
        "c": {
          "key": "c",
          "k": {
            "key": "k",
            "value": "vehicle",
            "name": "truck"
          }
        }
      },
      "o": {
        "key": "o",
        "w": {
          "key": "w",
          "e": {
            "key": "e",
            "l": {
              "key": "l",
              "value": "dig",
              "name": "trowel"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "h": {
    "key": "h",
    "a": {
      "key": "a",
      "t": {
        "key": "t",
        "value": "head",
        "name": "hat"
      },
      "l": {
        "key": "l",
        "t": {
          "key": "t",
          "value": "hold it",
          "name": "halt"
        }
      },
      "m": {
        "key": "m",
        "value": "pig",
        "name": "ham",
        "m": {
          "key": "m",
          "e": {
            "key": "e",
            "r": {
              "key": "r",
              "value": "nail",
              "name": "hammer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As for [the code that operates this](http://jsfiddle.net/4Yttq/9/), notes are on the comments:

```
function Trie(key) {
  this.key = key;
  this.value;
  //children are merged with this object since collision is minimal
}

Trie.prototype.put = function (name, value) {

  var node = this,
    nameLength = name.length,
    i = 0,
    currentLetter;

  //the only major change is this single loop which zips through the collection
  //if the node exists, make it current and proceed
  //if not, we create it, make it current and proceed
  for (i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
    currentLetter = name[i];
    node = node[currentLetter] || (node[currentLetter] = new Trie(currentLetter));
  }

  node.value = value;
  node.name = name;

};

Trie.prototype.get = function (name) {

  var node = this,
    nameLength = name.length,
    i, node;

  //same idea, zip through the collection
  //in this case we break if we hit a dead end
  for (i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
    if (!(node = node[name[i]])) break;
  }

  //only when the loop went over all letters will we find a value
  //if not, well, we don't find anything
  return (i === nameLength) ? node.value : 'not found';
};
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I'm planning on porting it back to C eventually, so I wanted to keep the linked lists; using `children` like this almost feels like cheating. I did retrofit the trie with a `children` property for the diagram example, but it doesn't take advantage of it at all. The constructor has the `undefined` checks to avoid creating  properties with undefined values, just to make the data easier to inspect... they could go. Other than that, this is only a few lines shorter... does it perform better?

Comment: @Dagg Ahh, I see. Performance, I'll post a jsPerf shortly.

Comment: +1 for the perf, although it's just a *tiny* bit faster for me... I think if use the sorted trie, I might be able to beat it. I tried adding the d3 stuff to your fiddle, thinking it would work since it used a `children` property, but d3 triggered an error like `d3 "Object #<Object> has no method 'map'` ... any idea what's going on there?

Comment: @Dagg I modified the latest revision, 9, to have no `children` property to further lessen the code. [Revision 8 still has `children`](http://jsfiddle.net/4Yttq/8/). Also, `children` isn't an array, but an object.

Comment: Ah, right, it's expecting an array. Merging `children` seems like a good idea, there shouldn't be any collision as long as no single-character property names are used. I'm still curious whether a sorted, linked trie can outperform this, or whether the linked trie code can be reduced significantly, but this is starting to look pretty good as a minimal JS solution.

Comment: Noob question here. Why put the functions as prototypes instead of putting them in function Trie(key) {}? Would there be any benefit to defining Trie as var Trie = function(key) {}?

Comment: @DanielJacobson Putting them on the prototype ensures that there is only one copy of that method in memory at a time. It also saves times when constructing the object to put it in the prototype rather than in the constructor.

Comment: I produced [a better jsperf](http://jsperf.com/tries/2) that doesn't re-run the implementation code on each test. It also compares against some similar data structures available in Javascript. On my system the JS Style implementation is about 6 times faster than the C-style. And of course, just using an Object-dictionary blows both out of the water.